# What are the books/pieces of literature that are read/mentioned/seen in Psycho-Pass?

Tags: psycho-pass

In *Psycho-Pass*, not only Makishima Shogo but Shinya Kogami were reading certain pieces of literature, but this pieces of literature shaped the series in a sense.

So far what I could see in the series that they were reading is the following:

1. *1984* - George Orwell
2. *A Revolution Sabotaged Before it Began* - Yasumi Iwakura
3. *Swann's Way* - Marcel Proust
4. Holy Bible

I know they have other references and books shown in the series, I have read some of these but I'm curious about.

What are other books/pieces of literature that are read/mentioned/seen?

Comment: In addition to the two posts above: In episode 17, there is also a book by Marquis de Sade. It's not possible to read the title, but given the length of it, I'd say it's probably "Justine, or the Misfortunes of Virtue"

Comment: Discipline and Punish: The Birth of the Prison by Michel Foucoult

Comment: There's also "Saraba, Eiga Yo".

Answer (score 31):

I might be missing a few referenced, but from what I can recall from skimming through the series again (in no particular order):

- [Midnight Plus One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Plus_One) by Gavin Lyall
- [Discourse on the Origin and Basis of Inequality Among Men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_on_Inequality) by Jean-Jacques Rousseau
- [Toward a Philosophy of History](https://books.google.com/books?id=6U4naz5DfsgC&dq=Toward+a+Philosophy+of+History+by+Jos%C3%A9+Ortega+y+Gasset&source=gbs_navlinks_s) by José Ortega y Gasset
- [Economy and Society](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_and_Society) by Max Weber
- Various works by William Shakespeare, such as [Twelfth Night](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_Night), [Macbeth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macbeth), [Titus Andronicus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titus_Andronicus), and [Hamlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamlet)
- [Carmilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmilla) and [In a Glass Darkly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_a_Glass_Darkly) by Joseph Sheridan Le Fanu
- [Heart of Darkness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_Darkness) by Joseph Conrad
- [Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Androids_Dream_of_Electric_Sheep%3F) by Philip K. Dick
- [Gulliver's Travels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulliver's_Travels) by Jonathan Swift
- Various [William Gibson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Gibson) works, such as [Johnny Mnemonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Mnemonic) and the [The Sprawl Trilogy (Neuromancer, Count Zero, Mona Lisa Overdrive)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprawl_trilogy)
- [Difference Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Difference_Engine) by William Gibson and Bruce Sterling
- [Pensées (Thoughts)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pens%C3%A9es) by Blaise Pascal
- [The Most Dangerous Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Most_Dangerous_Game) by Richard Connell
- [An Introduction to the Principles of Morals and Legislation](http://www.econlib.org/library/Bentham/bnthPML.html) by Jeremy Bentham
- [The Republic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Republic_(Plato)) by Plato
- [Beyond Good and Evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Good_and_Evil) by Friedrich Nietzsche
- [Violence: A New Approach](http://books.google.com/books/about/Violence.html?id=CIuNmAEACAAJ) by [Michel Wieviorka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Wieviorka)
- [The Conquest of Happiness](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Conquest_of_Happiness.html?id=--lefVQ_MYYC) by [Bertrand Russell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_Russell)
- [The Red and the Black](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Red_and_the_Black) by [Stendhal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stendhal)
- [Oathbreakers](http://books.google.com/books/about/Oathbreakers.html?id=IM17Mj4zDd8C) [by](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes_Lackey_bibliography#Vows_and_Honor) Mercedes Lackey (in reference to the subtitle of Ep. 16)
- [Faust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goethe's_Faust) by Johann Wolfgang von Goethe
- [Principles of Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Philosophy) by René Descartes
- [Crossroads: The Life and Afterlife of Blues Legend Robert Johnson](https://books.google.com/books/about/Crossroads.html?id=avU5AQAAIAAJ) by Tom Graves (in reference to the subtitle for Ep. 12)
- There are references to works of [Project Itoh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Itoh) ([Genocidal Organ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genocidal_Organ)?) and [Kierkegaard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8ren_Kierkegaard) ([The Sickness Unto Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sickness_Unto_Death)?), but no works are specifically named.

As mentioned before by others:

- [Nineteen Eighty-Four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four) by George Orwell
- [A Revolution Sabotaged Before it Began](http://books.google.com/books/about/%E3%81%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%8B%E3%81%98%E3%82%81%E8%A3%8F%E5%88%87%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E9%9D%A9%E5%91%BD.html?id=pbkfNwAACAAJ) (あらかじめ裏切られた革命) by Iwakami Yasumi
- [Swann's Way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Search_of_Lost_Time#Volume_One:_Swann.27s_Way) by Marcel Proust
- [The Bible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible) (New and Old Testament; e.g., Matthew 13:24-30, Book of Genesis)
- [Discipline and Punish: The Birth of the Prison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discipline_and_Punish) by Michel Foucault
- [Justine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justine_(Sade)) by Marquis de Sade

Certain movies are referenced as well:

- [The Man Who Stole the Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiy%C5%8D_o_Nusunda_Otoko) (in Ep. 5)
- [The Deer Hunter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Deer_Hunter) (in Ep. 11)
- Shuuji Terayama's theater drama play "[Saraba, eiga yo](http://www.theaterguide.co.jp/search_result/paid/detail.php?id=31190) (さらば、映画よ)."

In *Psycho-Pass: The Movie*:

- [Peau noire, masques blancs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peau_noire,_masques_blancs) and [The Wretched of the Earth](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Damn%C3%A9s_de_la_Terre) both by Frantz Fanon

Comment: swann's way - Marcel Proust
(at the very end of the 1st season)

Comment: Thanks so much! sorry i just came back so late /workkillsme

Comment: After reading Genocidal Organ from Project Itoh, I can say it develops how Makishima Shogo might have convinced people to start their killing spree.

Answer (score 2):

From [this AMV](https://youtu.be/EglGDGi_JNI?t=23), some other real-life books that could be recognized on the bookshelves:

- [Power/Knowledge](https://books.google.com/books/about/Power_Knowledge.html?id=Cai4AAAAIAAJ) by Michel Foucault
- [Critique of Pure Reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critique_of_Pure_Reason) by Immanuel Kant
- [The OTHER Heading](https://books.google.com/books?id=ojxpUU7fTrcC) by Jacques Derrida
- [OF GRAMMATOLOGY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Of_Grammatology) by Jacques Derrida
- [The ear of the other](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_ear_of_the_other.html?id=OtoZAAAAYAAJ) by Jacques Derrida

---

The Japanese-titled books are related to farming/agricultural technology. Instead of real-life books, these are more specific to *Psycho-Pass* universe regarding the advancement in those technologies:

- センターピボットがもたらす農業改革[...] ([...] Agricultural Reform Caused by Center Pivot)
- [...]組み換え植物の極？を？[...] ([...] a Recombinant Plant [...])
- 最強の農業ドローンシステム (The Strongest Agricultural Drone System)
- 総合防除と生物農業の干？[...] ([...] Integrated Pest Control and Biological Agriculture)
- [...]ウィルス拡散の脅威 (Threat of [...] virus spread)
- ウカノミタマ ([Uka-no-Mitama](https://psychopass.wikia.com/wiki/Uka-no-Mitama_Defense_Virus))
- 無敵の盾 (Invincible shield)
- [...]品目による自給体制のリ[...] ([...] Self-sufficiency System with Items [...])
- [...]与える農薬の影響 ([...] Influence of Pesticide Given)
- ハイパーオーツは人類を賄う ([Hyper-oats](https://psychopass.wikia.com/wiki/Hyper-oats) Maintain Humanity)

Comment: Would very appreciate if someone could mention in which episode this specific scene on AMV is taken from.