# What Japanese books/piece of literatures that are shown in Psycho-Pass?

Tags: japanese-language, psycho-pass

On this scene and other bookshelves of [a Psycho-Pass AMV](https://youtu.be/EglGDGi_JNI?t=23), there are some Japanese books.

What are they?

Comment: This seems to be an interesting question, but I think it would probably be covered under the other question, hence my VTC as a duplicate.

Comment: This specific question is addressed in [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/47736/37809).